msiexec error code 1305 - installing HRBlock 2024 software
Windows 10 Home version 22H2 OS build 19045.5131 All updates are current
I am trying to install HRBlock 2024 software and getting the follow error:
Error 1305.Error reading from file C:\ProgramData\TaxCut\2024\cache{5EFA07C5-A897-4E10-BAB4-7D0485841F9F}
HR Block 2024.msi. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
The file does exist.
During installation, it appears to create the C:\ProgramData\TaxCut\2024\cache{5EFA07C5-A897-4E10-BAB4-7D0485841F9F} folder and then copies the HR Block 2024.msi file into that folder.
The error is apparently generated when attempting to access the HR Block 2024.msi file later in the install process.
I have generated an MSI installation log file and included what I think is a relevant snippet:
MSI (s) (F4:CC) [15:57:28:918]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 102, llSequenceNumber: 0, szDescription: "Installed HR Block 2024.".
MSI (s) (F4:CC) [15:57:38:972]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0, llSequenceNumber: 867.
MSI (s) (F4:CC) [15:57:38:977]: Error: Failed to access database: C:\ProgramData\TaxCut\2024\cache{5EFA07C5-A897-4E10-BAB4-7D0485841F9F}\HR Block 2024.msi
MSI (s) (F4:CC) [15:57:38:980]: MainEngineThread is returning 2
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:38:982]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 13, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 867, szDescription: "".
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:38:986]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:38:989]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:38:992]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:38:994]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:38:997]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:39:002]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2
MSI (s) (F4:90) [15:57:39:007]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied. Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (1C:60) [15:57:39:010]: Note: 1: 1305 2: C:\ProgramData\TaxCut\2024\cache{5EFA07C5-A897-4E10-BAB4-7D0485841F9F}\HR Block 2024.msi 3: 0
Error 1305.Error reading from file C:\ProgramData\TaxCut\2024\cache{5EFA07C5-A897-4E10-BAB4-7D0485841F9F}\HR Block 2024.msi. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
MSI (c) (1C:60) [15:57:42:217]: Product: H&R Block Deluxe + Efile + State 2024 -- Error 1305.Error reading from file C:\ProgramData\TaxCut\2024\cache{5EFA07C5-A897-4E10-BAB4-7D0485841F9F}\HR Block 2024.msi. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this installation issue?

I would contract support for the software.  There is clearly an issue with their installer.
